# Converting VB.NET to libCURL - how to check what is sent out

Tags: c++, vb.net, libcurl

ALL,
I have following code in ASP:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    <form id="Form2" Method="Post" EncType="Multipart/Form-Data" RunAt="Server">

   <%-- The File upload Html control --%>
   Choose Your File  To Upload <BR>
   <Input Name="MyFile" id="MyFile" Type="File" RunAt="Server">
   <BR>

   <%-- A button - when clicked the form is submitted and the
            Upload_Click event handler is fired... --%>
   <Input id="Submit1" Type="Submit" Value="Upload"
             RunAt="Server">

    </form> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the following algorythm in VB.NET on the client side:

1. Set content-type to be "multipart/form-data;
   boundary=---------------------------" + timestamp
2. Write "\n\r-----------------------------" + timestamp + "\n\r"
3. Write "Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MyFile";
   filename="12345.bmp"\r\nContent-Type: image/bitmap\r\n\r\n"
4. POST'ing the content of the "12345.bmp"

I'm trying to convert this to C++ with libCURL.

Here is what I did:

```
        wxString header = wxString::Format( "Content-Disposition: form-data;
name=\"MyFile\"; filename=\"%s\"", fileName );
        post = curl_slist_append( post, "Content-Type: multipart/form-data;
boundary=---------------------------12345" );
        post = curl_slist_append( post, header.c_str() );
        if( !post )
        {
                return;
        }
        post = curl_slist_append( post, "Content-Type: image/bitmap" );
        if( !post )
        {
                curl_slist_free_all( post );
                return;
        }
        result = curl_formadd( &first, &last, CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "name",
CURLFORM_FILE, (const char *) fileName.c_str(), CURLFORM_END );
        result = curl_formadd( &first, &last, CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "filename",
CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, (const char *) fileName.c_str(),
CURLFORM_CONTENTHEADER, post, CURLFORM_END );
        result = curl_formadd(&first,  &last, CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "submit",
CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, "send", CURLFORM_END );
        if( result )
        {
                curl_slist_free_all( post );
                curl_formfree( first );
                return;
        }
        FILE *fp = fopen( "session.log", "w+" );
        if( !fp )
        {
                curl_slist_free_all( post );
                curl_formfree( first );
                return;
        }
        curl_easy_setopt( handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L );
        curl_easy_setopt( handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1L );
        curl_easy_setopt( handle, CURLOPT_STDERR, fp );
        curl_easy_setopt( handle, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, errorMsg );
        curl_easy_setopt( handle, CURLOPT_URL, "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Default.aspx" );
        curl_easy_setopt( handle, CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, first );
        error = curl_easy_perform( handle );
        if( !error )
        {
                curl_slist_free_all( post );
                curl_formfree( first );
                return;
        }
        curl_slist_free_all( post );
        curl_formfree( first );
        curl_easy_setopt( handle, CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, NULL );
        curl_easy_setopt( handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, NULL );
```

But unfortunately it is failing.
What do people use on Windows to check how the packets are sent out?
Or maybe someone can spot a problem in my code transition?

Thank you.

Comment: You may want to try Wireshark. It can capture the packets send from or to an interface.

Comment: @Burkhard, I installed Wireshark, but looking at its capture there is a strange thing. In it's log it says "Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"; filename="112626165626.bmp" which is not what I tried to send. Any idea why? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry Igor, no more ideas from me. Good luck!

Comment: @Burkhard, actually I found the problem and another problem and they are fixed. Now are you familiar with libCURL? I have one outstanding issue that is not such an easy solver...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but from reading the wxString docs I wonder if

```
wxString header = wxString::Format( "Content-Disposition: form-data;
name=\"MyFile\"; filename=\"%s\"", fileName );
```

shouldn't be

```
wxString header = wxString::Format( "Content-Disposition: form-data;
name=\"MyFile\"; filename=\"%s\"", fileName.c_str() );
```

Hope this helps.